# How to put a loading spinner for an iframe in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe, gif

I have a couple Google Maps iframes embedded in my WordPress page but they are rather large maps that take forever to load. I've tried multiple different plugins to try and have a loading spinner show up until the map is actually loaded but it seems they only work for images and the like....i cannot get it to work for a google maps iframe. is there any plugin that would insert either a loading image or a spinner gif?